# Color spaces, gamma and image enhancement

Tags: opengl, rgb, gamma, srgb, gamma-distribution

*Color space*. Well, everybody knows about RGB: three values normalized in the range [0.0,1.0], which have the meaning of the intensity of the color components Red Green Blue; this intensity is meant as linear, isn't?

*Gamma*. As far I can understand, gamma is a function which maps RGB color components to another value. Googling on this, I've seen linear functions and non linear functions...
Linear functions seems to scale RGB components, so it seems to tune image brightness; non linear functions seems to "decompress" darker/lighter components.

Now, I'm starting to implement an image viewer, which shall display different image formats as texture. I'd like to modify the gamma of these images, so I should build up a fragment shader and run over the textured quad. Fine, but how do I determine the right gamma correction?

OpenGL works using linear RGB color space, using floating point components. Indeed, I could compute gamma-corrected values starting from those values (with special floating point precision), so they are displayed after having clamped the gamma-corrected value.

First, I shall determine the gamma ramp. How could I determine it? (analitically or using lookup tables)

Then, I came up to investigate on the OpenGL extension EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, which seems very related with the extension [EXT_texture_sRGB](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_sRGB.txt).

EXT_texture_sRGB introduce a new texture format which is used to linearize textel values into RGB linear space. (footnote 1) In this way, I'm aware of sRGB color space and use it as linear RGB color space.

Instead, EXT_framebuffer_sRGB extension allows me to encode linear RGB values onto the sRGB framebuffer, without worrying about it.

...

Wait, all this information for what? If I can use sRGB framebuffer and load sRGB textures, process that textures without sRGB conversions... why should I correct gamma?

Maybe can I correct gamma all the same, even on a sRGB buffer? Or I better not? And brightness and contrast: shall they applied before or after gamma correction?

That's a lot of information, I'm getting confused now. Hope that someone of you can explain me more all these concepts! Thank you.

...

There's another question. In the case the device gamma is different from the "standard" 2.2, how do I "accumulate" different gamma corrections? I don't know if it is clear: in the case image RGB values are already corrected for a monitor with a gamma value of 2.2, but the monitor has a gamma of value 2.8, how to I correct gamma?

---

(1) Here is some extract to highlight what I mean:

> The sRGB color space is based on typical (non-linear) monitor
>       characteristics expected in a dimly lit office.  It has been
>       standardized by the International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC)
>       as IEC 61966-2-1. The sRGB color space roughly corresponds to 2.2
>       gamma correction.

> Does this extension provide any sort of sRGB framebuffer formats
>           or guarantee images rendered with sRGB textures will "look good"
>           when output to a device supporting an sRGB color space?
>
> ```
>    RESOLVED:  No.
>
>   Whether the displayed framebuffer is displayed to a monitor that
>     faithfully reproduces the sRGB color space is beyond the scope
>     of this extension.  This involves the gamma correction and color
>     calibration of the physical display device.
>
>     With this extension, artists can author content in an sRGB color
>     space and provide that sRGB content for use as texture imagery
>     that can be properly converted to linear RGB and filtered as part
>     of texturing in a way that preserves the sRGB distribution of
>     precision, but that does NOT mean sRGB pixels are output
>     to the framebuffer.  Indeed, this extension provides texture
>     formats that convert sRGB to linear RGB as part of filtering.
>
>     With programmable shading, an application could perform a
>     linear RGB to sRGB conversion just prior to emitting color
>     values from the shader.  Even so, OpenGL blending (other than
>     simple modulation) will perform linear math operations on values
>     stored in a non-linear space which is technically incorrect for
>     sRGB-encoded colors.
>
>     One way to think about these sRGB texture formats is that they
>     simply provide color components with a distribution of values
>     distributed to favor precision towards 0 rather than evenly
>     distributing the precision with conventional non-sRGB formats
>     such as GL_RGB8.
> ```

Comment: I would say I shall render on a monitor which is not for consumers, but it actually specialized on HDR image processing. At the moment I have no monitor specification, but I suspect I shall apply gamma correction during rendering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately OpenGL by itself doesn't define a colour space. It's just defined that the RGB values passed to OpenGL form a linear vector space. The values of the rendered framebuffer are then sent to the display device as they are. OpenGL just passes through the value.

Gamma services two purposes:

- Sensory perception is nonlinear
- In the old days, display devices had a nonlinear response

The gamma correction is used to compensate for both.

The transformation is just "linear value V to some power Gamma", i.e. y(v) = v^gamma

Colorspace transformations involve the complete chain from input values to whats sent to the display, so this includes the gamma correction. This also implies that you should not manipulate the gamma ramp youself.

For a long time the typical Gamma value used to be 2.2. However this caused some undesireable quantisation of low values, so Adobe introduced a new colour space, called sRGB which has a linear part for low values and a powerfunction with exponential ~2.3 for the higher values. Most display devices these days use sRGB. Also most image files these days are in sRGB.

So if you have a sRGB image, and display it as-is on a sRGB display device with a linear gamma ramp configured on the device (i.e. video driver gamma=1) you're good by simply using sRGB texturing and framebuffer and not doing anything else.

*EDIT due to comments*

Just to summarize:

- Use a ARB_framebuffer_sRGB framebuffer, so that the results of the linear OpenGL processing are properly color transformed by the driver http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_sRGB.txt
- Linearize all colour inputs to OpenGL
- Textures in sRGB colour space should be passed through EXT_texture_sRGB http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_sRGB.txt
- Don't gamma correct the output values (the sRGB format framebuffer will take care of this)

If your system does not support sRGB framebuffers:

- Set a linear colour ramp on your display device.

  - Windows http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536529(v=vs.85).aspx
  - X11 can be done though xgamma http://www.xfree86.org/current/xgamma.1.html
- create (linear) framebuffer objects, to linear rendering in the framebuffer object. The use of a FBO is, to properly to blending, which only works in linear colour space.
- draw the final render result from the FBO to the window using a fragment shader that applies the desired colour (gamma and other) corrections.

Comment: Indeed the OpenGL driver correct framebuffer RGB values after I swapper it? In this case, if I want to apply gamma correction in my shader, only for my application, I shall detect the current system setting, isn't?

Comment: @Luca: In principle yes. However you will run into the problem, that within OpenGL you work in a linear color space (which is what you want), and any gamma correction would turn your colours nonlinear. Unfortunately your graphics driver assumes the incoming fragments being linear. And that's where the problems begin: The applied correction may be something completely different than a simple gamma curve. For example your target device expects X'Y'Z' and this is configured in the driver. Then you passing the nonlinear values will mess things up in the conversion.

Comment: @Luca: As a general rule you should stick to linear colour transformations; not just in OpenGL but in all situations. If you know the exact transformations applied by driver and display device you can take those into account. Also some display drivers (those of professional graphics cards) provide special pixelformat configurations where the values from the application are fed directly to the device without intermediate correction. Only in this case you can safely apply nonlinear transformations, but then of course have to do all corrections yourself.

Comment: @Luca: So to conclude things: Linearize everything you pass to OpenGL using some color management system (littleCMS for example); if your images are sRGB use sRGB texturing. And then stick to a linear color processing. The graphics driver will perform the neccesary corrections to match with your display device. So don't lie to the driver.

Comment: Wow. So I have to instruct the driver about gamma correction (I suspect using SetDeviceGammaRamp or some driver entry point). Do you have any pointer on those pixel formats? Just a curiosity!

Comment: @Luca: Just forget about gamma correcting on the output side. Instead apply an inverse gamma correction that will linearize the image data before you pass it to OpenGL. If your image has a gamma of say 2.6, apply a gamma of 1/2.6 and then pass this to OpenGL. sRGB is ufortunately a bit cumbersome to work with, a simple gamma correction does not do the trick. That's whereh EXT_texture_sRGB comes in.

Comment: @Luca: Oh and please read the article linked by @Bethor, it truly is a Gem!

Comment: @datenwolf Can you verify if I've got this right? While using an sRGB framebuffer, the values are stored in the sRGB space itself, while all operations involved will be automatically translated to be performed in the linear space. This produces higher quality than a manual method of using a regular linear color buffer then gamma-correcting (with a shader) in post processing. Because the sRGB framebuffer linear operations will perform in full precision in the hardware, while the manual method truncates values to 8 linear bits at every pass.

Comment: @StevenLu: No, there is no decrease in quality, since in the shader all values can be hold and calculated as floating point values with more than 8 bits. But using sRGB textures and framebuffers may result in better performance, due to optimizations built into the driver. But you're right, that the colors are left in sRGB space and only get linearized upon sampling and blending and delinearized when the fragments is transferred to on-screen.

Answer (score 6):

> Wait, all this information for what? If I can use sRGB framebuffer and load sRGB textures, process that textures without sRGB conversions... why should I correct gamma?

Generally, you don't. The purpose of the sRGB texturing and framebuffers is so that you *don't* have to manually do gamma correction. Reads from sRGB textures are converted to a linear colorspace, and writes to sRGB framebuffers take linear RGB values and convert them to sRGB values. This is all automatic, and more to the point *free*, performance-wise.

The only time you will need to do gamma correction is if the monitor's gamma does not match the sRGB gamma approximation of 2.2 gamma. Rare is the monitor that does this.

Your textures do not *have* to be in sRGB colorspace. However, most image creation applications will save images in sRGB and works with colors in sRGB, so odds are most of your textures are *already* in sRGB whether you want them to be or not. The sRGB texture feature simply allows you to actually get the *correct* color values, rather than the color values you've been getting up until now.

> And brightness and contrast: shall they applied before or after gamma correction?

I don't know what you mean by brightness and contrast. That's something that should be set by the monitor, not your application. But virtually *all* math operations you will want to do on image data should be done in a linear colorspace. Therefore, if you are given an image in the sRGB colorspace, you need to linearize it before you can do any math on it. The sRGB texture feature makes this free, rather than having to do complex shader math.

Comment: How do I know whether the image loader function actually gives me sRGB values or already-corrected RGB values? (Yes, too broad as statement; i.e. set jpeglib and openexr as image loaders).

Comment: @Luca OpenEXR is for floating-point images. Those should be in linear colorspace, and sRGB isn't allowed for floating-point images anyway. The JPEG format has color profiles that tell what colorspace the data is, but sRGB is pretty common there. Similarly, PNGs can have color profile information embedded in them.

Comment: True, OpenEXR should be linear. Unfortunately some programs emit nonlinear OpenEXR. So in case of doubt double check it.

Answer (score 1):

## RGB

> RGB: three values normalized in the range [0.0,1.0], which have the meaning of the intensity of the color components Red Green Blue; **this intensity is meant as linear, isn't**?

No. RGB values are meaningless numbers unless their relevance to a particular space/encoding is defined. They may be linear, gamma encoded, or log encoded, or use a compound transfer curve like the Rec709 and sRGB specs.

Also, they are relative to their primaries and whitepoint as defined in the colorspace, so for instance, #00FF00 in sRGB is a different color than #00FF00 in DCI-P3.

To define how an RGB pixel value should be displayed, you need not only the RGB triplet, but you need to know the colorspace it is intended for, which needs to include the primary coordinates, whitepoint, and transfer curve.

sRGB is the default "standard" RGB colorspace for the Web and general purpose computing. It is *related* to Rec709, the standard colorspace for HDTV.

## GAMMA aka TRANSFER CURVE

> Gamma. As far I can understand, gamma is a function which maps RGB color components to another value.

Image gamma takes advantage of the non-linearity of human perception to make the best use of the limited data size of 8 bit per channel images. The human eye is more sensitive to changes in darker colors, so more bits ae used to define the darker colors in a gamma encoded image.

Before digital, gamma was also used in the NTSC broadcast system which suppressed the apparent noise in the signal, in a way similar to how image gamma prevents an 8-bit per channel image from having "banding" artifacts.

> First, I shall determine the gamma ramp. How could I determine it? (analitically or using lookup tables)

Gamma *CURVE*. The sRGB gamma curve is easily accessed. Here is the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation) for go from sRGB to linear. You can also use the "simplified" method which simply uses a 2.2 exponent curve:

`linearVideo = sRGBvideo^2.2` and the simplified inverse, to go back to sRGB:

`sRGBvideo = linearVideo^0.4545`

Using the simplified version will introduce some minor gamma errors, it is advised to use the "correct" curve for critical operations or where an image will be "round tripped" multiple times.

> There's another question. In the case the device gamma is different from the "standard" 2.2, how do I "accumulate" different gamma corrections? I don't know if it is clear: in the case image RGB values are already corrected for a monitor with a gamma value of 2.2, but the monitor has a gamma of value 2.8, how to I correct gamma?

2.8 ??? What monitor is that? PAL? This is unusual — While the PAL spec says that, 2.8 isn't "practical". Monitors are typically around 2.3 to 2.5 depending on how they are setup. When you adjust black level and contrast (white level) you are in essence adjusting the perceived gamma to match the viewing environment (room lighting).

Just FYI, while the sRGB "signal" has an encoded gamma of 1/2.2, the monitor normally adds an exponent of about 1.1

For Rec709, the encoded signal has an effective gamma of about 1/1.9 ish but the monitor in the reference viewing environment is about 2.4

In both cases there is an intentional system gamma gain.

If you wanted to encode an image with a gamma for a 2.8 display and you wanted no system gamma gain, then the exponent is 1/2.8

The "highest" gamma in common use is for digital cinema (and also Rec2020), at 2.6  For those of you thinking PAL & 2.8, I encourage you to read Poynton on that subject:

### HIGHLY RECOMMENDED READING

[Charles Poynton's Gamma FAQ](https://poynton.ca/GammaFAQ.html) is an easy read and completely describes these issues and why they are important in an image pipeline. Also read his Color FAQ at the same link.

## A FEW WORDS ON LINEAR vs sRGB

Working on images in a linear workspace is typically ideal, as it not only simplifies the math, but emulates light in the real world. Light in the world works in a linear manner (additive). But if working in linear, you need adequate bit depth, and 8 bits is not enough.

Human perception is NON linear. Image gamma encoding takes advantage of the non linearity to make the most use of 8 bit image containers. When you convert to linear YOU NEED MORE BITS. 12 bit per chan is considered a minimum, but 16bit float is the minimum "recommend best practice" for linear workspaces.

If using textures in a linear rendering environment, those textures need to be transformed to a linear space (and often a deeper bit depth). While the added bits increase data bandwidth, the simplified math often allows faster computation.

sRGB is a DISPLAY REFERRED space, it is intended for DISPLAY PURPOSES, and for storing images in a compact "display ready" state. Black is 0 and white is 255, and the transfer curve is close to 1/2.2

sRGB is based on Rec709 (HDTV), and uses identical primaries and whitepoint. But the transfer curve and data encoding are different. Rec709 is intended for display on a higher gamma monitor in a darkened livingroom, and encodes black at 16 and white at 235.