# Check color encoding in the default framebuffer draw buffer for SRGB

Tags: draw, default, framebuffer, opengl-3, srgb

I am in the process of implementing sRGB space in my application.

From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397817/color-spaces-gamma-and-image-enhancement), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386199/when-to-call-glenablegl-framebuffer-srgb), [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#sRGB_colorspace) and [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Colorspace) I should operate in linear RGB (LRGB) space for the whole pipeline and I dont have to care about any gamma correction since OpenGL will take care about it for me given I enable `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB​` and the image is either `GL_SRGB8` or `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8`.

So my idea is to be sure I submit inputs in LRGB space and then I render my final texture (doing depth peeling) on the default framebuffer that will take care of porting my colors to the SRGB space so that I will see them on LRGB on my monitor.

Ok, now I want to check the default draw buffer of the default framebuffer.

```
        int[] drawBuffer = new int[1];

        gl3.glGetIntegerv(GL3.GL_DRAW_BUFFER, drawBuffer, 0);

        System.out.println("draw buffer " + (drawBuffer[0] == GL3.GL_BACK ? "BACK " : drawBuffer[0]));
```

this confirms my draw buffer is GL_BACK, now I want to check the color encoding

```
        int[] framebufferAttachmentParameter = new int[1];

        gl3.glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL3.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL3.GL_BACK,
                GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING, framebufferAttachmentParameter, 0);
```

but `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv` fails:

> glGetError() returned the following error codes after a call to glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv( 0x8CA9,  0x405,  0x8210, <[I>,  0x0): GL_INVALID_ENUM ( 1280 0x500)

Reading [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameter.xml) they say

> If the default framebuffer is bound to target then attachment must be one of
>               GL_FRONT_LEFT, GL_FRONT_RIGHT, GL_BACK_LEFT, or
>               GL_BACK_RIGHT

But my code say my draw buffer is `GL_BACK`. Reading [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Default_Framebuffer) they say the `GL_BACK` is just an alias that indicates both `GL_BACK_LEFT` and `GL_BACK_RIGHT` if I do stereotic rendering.

So my questions are:

- am I right assuming that I am writing to `GL_BACK_LEFT` given my draw buffer returns `GL_BACK`
- how can I check if stereotic rendering is on/off? Of course since I dont know even how to turn it on, I assume it is off. But is something I do by just enabling both GL_BACK/FRONT_LEFT/RIGHT buffers or something else?
- can I turn on SRGB space on the default draw buffer of the default framebuffer?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on the opengl forums, I think it can be useful for anyone visiting this question if I leave this here

https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/185198-Check-color-encoding-in-the-default-framebuffer-draw-buffer-for-SRGB?p=1263059#post1263059